# How to convert Keras LSTM model into tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, lstm

I have trained a LSTM model on pytorch, and converted it into Keras lstm model with `set_weights` method. The performance looks almost the same. However, I need to convert the model into lstm model with older tensorflow version (V1.xx), by using `tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell` method. What confused me was that I did not find any method that can load lstm weights from numpy like arrays. The only method I find is loading saved checkpoints, but not suitable for me.
Any suggestion for me? Thanks.